# java.net.MalformedURLException:no protocol

Tags: java

I've the following code

```
    String url = "http://e2e-soaservices:44000/3.1/StandardDocumentService?wsdl";
    //createSOAPRequest(); 
    SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);
```

in the createSOAPRequest Method:-

```
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
    File fXmlFile = new File("src/XML/gen_VDD7S0PLYPAS058_1409900400000_2.xml");
    String xmlStr=finalXmlString(fXmlFile);
    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    docBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);   
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();   
    Document doc=docBuilder.parse(xmlStr);  
    System.out.println("dasdasdasd"+doc.toString());
    String serverURI = "http://www.aaancnuie.com/DCS/2012/01/DocumentCreation/IStandardDocumentService/CreateDocuments";
    
    // SOAP Envelope
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("example", serverURI);
    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
    soapBody.setTextContent(xmlStr);
    soapMessage.saveChanges();
    return soapMessage;
```

The error message

```
Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server
java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: http%3A%2F%2Fe2e-soaservices%3A44000%2F3.1%2FStandardDocumentService%3Fwsdl
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:567)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
    at SOAPCLIENTSAAJ.main(SOAPCLIENTSAAJ.java:36)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `encode` your URL.
Special character which have to be escaped.

Escaping example:

```
String url = "http://e2e-soaservices:44000/3.1/StandardDocumentService?wsdl";
String yourURLStr = java.net.URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(yourURLStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, according to the stacktrace that you posted, the actual problem is that you are trying to use a URL where various characters have been %-escaped when they shouldn't be.

```
  http%3A%2F%2Fe2e-soaservices%3A44000%2F3.1%2FStandardDocumentService%3Fwsdl
```

In particular, the initial `http%3A%2F%2F` should actually be `http://`.  The URL parser looks for initial `:` ... and when it can't find it, it complains (correctly!) that there is no protocol component to the URL.

I note that the error message does not match the URL in your code.  I don't know what is going on there .... but if the URL in the error message is what is actually being used, then it needs to be **decoded** (not encoded).

---

If this is not making sense, please provide a proper complete [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), AND the stack trace that you get from executing that example.